# Can't put buttons inside frame that's inside another frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a grid placing a top, center, and footer frames, then I'm making frames inside the Center frame (I'll call them subframes as I don't know what to refer to them as). When I try to pack/grid/place a button inside the subframes it won't work. If I grid the buttons, they appear at the bottom of all top-level frames which doesn't make any sense to me since I put them in their appropriate subframes... This is really hard to explain, but that's the best I can do.

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import math

# gui
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Bid Generator')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 880))

# main containers
top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#00c3ff', height=75)
center = tk.Frame(root, bg='white')
footer = tk.Frame(root, bg='black', height=100)

# layout of the main containers
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
center.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")
footer.grid(row=2, sticky="ew")

# distributing equal weight (priority) to center frame columns
center.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
center.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
center.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(8, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(9, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(11, weight=1)
center.grid_rowconfigure(12, weight=1)


# label widget for the top frame
aibs_label = tk.Label(top_frame, text='Bid Generator', bg='#00c3ff').pack()

# Supported bank frames
bank_label = tk.Label(center, text='Supported Bank?', bg="gray", height=20).grid(row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
bank_left = tk.Frame(center, bg="red", padx=10, pady=10, height=10, width=10).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
bank_mid = tk.Frame(center, bg="green", padx=10, pady=10, height=10, width=10).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
bank_right = tk.Frame(center, bg="blue", padx=10, pady=10, height=10, width=10).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="ew")
bank_yes = tk.Button(bank_left, text="Yes", width=24, height=3).grid()
bank_no = tk.Button(bank_mid, text="No", width=24, height=3).grid()
bank_name = tk.Button(bank_right, text="entry", width=24, height=3).grid()


# credit cards
cc_label = tk.Label(center, text='Credit cards?', bg="gray", height=20).grid(row=1, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
cc_left = tk.Frame(center, bg="red", height=10, width=10).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")
cc_mid = tk.Frame(center, bg="green", height=10, width=10).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ew")
cc_right = tk.Frame(center, bg="blue", height=10, width=10).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="ew")

# checks frames
chks_label = tk.Label(center, text='Checks?', bg="gray", height=20).grid(row=3, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
chks_left = tk.Frame(center, bg="red", height=10, width=10).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="ew")
chks_mid = tk.Frame(center, bg="green", height=10, width=10).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="ew")
chks_right = tk.Frame(center, bg="blue", height=10, width=10).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="ew")

# payroll frames
pr_label = tk.Label(center, text='Payroll?', bg="gray", height=20).grid(row=5, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
pr_left = tk.Frame(center, bg="red", height=10, width=10).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="ew")
pr_mid = tk.Frame(center, bg="green", height=10, width=10).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky="ew")
pr_right = tk.Frame(center, bg="blue", height=10, width=10).grid(row=6, column=2, sticky="ew")

# sales tax frames
st_label = tk.Label(center, text='Sales Tax?', bg="gray", height=20).grid(row=7, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
st_left = tk.Frame(center, bg="red", height=10, width=10).grid(row=8, column=0, sticky="ew")
st_mid = tk.Frame(center, bg="green", height=10, width=10).grid(row=8, column=1, sticky="ew")
st_right = tk.Frame(center, bg="blue",  height=10, width=10).grid(row=8, column=2, sticky="ew")

# workers comp frames
wc_label = tk.Label(center, text='Workers Comp?', bg="gray", height=20).grid(row=9, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
wc_left = tk.Frame(center, bg="red", height=10, width=10).grid(row=10, column=0, sticky="ew")
wc_mid = tk.Frame(center, bg="green", height=10, width=10).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky="ew")
wc_right = tk.Frame(center, bg="blue", height=10, width=10).grid(row=10, column=2, sticky="ew")

# qbox frames
qbox_label = tk.Label(center, text='Qbox?', bg="gray", height=20).grid(row=11, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
qbox_left = tk.Frame(center, bg="red", height=100, width=10).grid(row=12, column=0, sticky="ew")
qbox_mid = tk.Frame(center, bg="green", height=10, width=10).grid(row=12, column=1, sticky="ew")
qbox_right = tk.Frame(center, bg="blue", height=10, width=10).grid(row=12, column=2, sticky="ew")






# End of line
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: All the `Frame(...).grid(...) ` code return None. So the Buttons don't have the Frame as a parent. You need to create the Frame. Then grid it in a separate statement.

Comment: Try to do all the `grid` separately on a new line. Because using `grid()` in the same line saves `None` to the variable instead of the widget because `grid()` returns `None`... I think this will solve your issue...

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the explanation! I do however have a bunch of white space in between frames, do you know how to correct that?